# Django Staticfiles Is Saved In An Unexpected Location

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

[image: static settings]

I followed the documentation at [Django 2.2 Static Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00sEd.jpg)

This is the `settings.py` file:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = "/STATIC"
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00sEd.jpg): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/ but to my surprise, anytime I run `manage.py collectstatic` it keeps storing the static files in the C:/ not inside the project static folder. The image below explains further what I am saying [The settings of static file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00sEd.jpg) [image: Static folder inside project] [image: Static folder that was created automatically inside C:/]

Comment: show your `settings.py`. Likely you used `/static/` instead of `static/`

Comment: wow!!! Thanks a lot @WillemVanOnsem, that is simply the reason.

Answer (score 1):

As [**`STATIC_ROOT`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#static-root) you should use:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
```

without a leading slash (`/`), otherwise this means you start from the *root* of your filesystem. With `static/` it means the directory `static` relative to the current working directory.

Of course you can also specify a *different* directory that determines where you store your static files.